# Horizontal RecyclerView - when selected item is out of viewport (scrolling left/right), change background of the most left/right item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I have a horizontal recyclerview that can be scrolled both left and right (around 50 items in it). When the selected item in the recycler view is out of viewport, because I scrolled right, I want to change the background of the most right item, as an indicator that selected item is on the right, and same if I scroll left.

Not sure if I could use findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(), because how would I get the position of the right/left most item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the right most item, you can use `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` and to get the left most item, you can use `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`